# How to prove $a\cos(\omega t + \phi_1) + b\cos(\omega t + \phi_2) = c\sin(d t + \phi_3)$

Tags: trigonometry

One of my tutoring students has been given an equation representing the first half of the equality in the title, and has to find $c$, $d$ and $\phi_3$ for the second half of the inequality.

I know there's a way to do it for the LHS without the phis, but I can't figure out how to do it with the phis included.

It's quite possible that $d = \omega$, but I figured making the question more general might help the solution be more useful.

Thank you all in advance for any help you may be able to give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expand $\cos$ and $\sin$ in the LHS to get $A\cos(\omega t) + B\sin(\omega t)$ in the LHS ($A$ and $B$ are the new coefficients of $\cos$ and $\sin$).

Then, we can write this as $$\sqrt{A^2+B^2} \sin(\omega t + c)$$ where $$c = \cos^{-1} \frac{B}{\sqrt{A^2+B^2}}$$

Equating with the RHS, we get $c = \sqrt{A^2+B^2}$, $d = \omega$, and $\phi_3 = c$

Comment: I'm not following the steps you're using - why does c equal the inverse cos bit as well as $\sqrt( A^2 + B^2)$?

Comment: Expand $\sin(\omega t + c)$ in terms of $\sin(\omega t)$ and $\cos(\omega t)$, and you will see that it is equal to $A\cos(\omega t) + B\sin(\omega t)$

Comment: Yeah I vaguely managed to figure it out eventually